# PHP how to get full names form month, day in language from browser

Tags: php, setlocale, http-accept-language

I want to show the names of days and month in the language the browser provides.
So I can set the language using setlocale, like : `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL')`
Then the names are all in dutch.
And I can get the browser language with: `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]`
So if my browser is Dutch `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` returns 'nl' not 'nl_NL'
But `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl')` does not work.
I need a conversion method, so nl is converted to nl_NL.
Not only dutch (that would be simple), but also the other languages.
Or a completely other method :-)

regards Jan

Comment: Note that `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` can contain multiple languages, or even not exist.

Comment: Hi KIKO, yes i know. i want to set en-EN as default language.